# C implementation of mersenne twister that produces results equal to mt_rand in PHP?

Tags: php, c, mersenne-twister

I'm working on some apps, and need to validate some results of random number generation. I can do it in PHP, the same as the source app, but it's slow. We'd like to code the validator in C for speed. The issue is that every implementation of the MT algo in C produces different results than it does in PHP (using the same seed).

The big issue is the data from PHP has already been made, and has been database logged for over two months now - we cannot just change the generator in PHP (to a class that I know matches standard C results).

I believe it has to do with integer size and the signed/unsigned issue PHP has -  our 32 bit implementation has the MAX_RAND at 2.147billion (or whatever the exact number is) while the same datatype in C is -2.147bil to 2.147 bil if signed, and 4.3bil if unsigned.

Is there a way to restrict the max integer size in C? Or does anyone know of an implementation where, using the same seed, we can produce the same results? I really don't want to do this in PHP - it's absurdly slow in comparison.

Comment: Side issue - I am playing with the code, and part of the mt process XOR's a uint32_t - which somehow winds up negative? How is that possible? I took a uint32_t, set it to zero, added 5,000,000,000 to it, and it rolled over to 700mil and change. How can XOR'ing it make an unsigned integer negative?

Comment: An unsigned variable can never be negative. You must be assigning it to a signed variable. The top half of the unsigned range corresponds to negative values of the corresponding signed type.

Comment: It was a display issue. I was showing it with a printf %d instead of %u. Original issue still stands however.

Comment: That was my other guess.

Comment: I've spent the last 2 hours combing over the PHP source and the MT C library I am using. They APPEAR to be the same. It may be that if a PHP variable exceeds 2.147bil it auto-converts to a float, where in C it loops back over to 0 (uint32_t)?

Comment: I think that's true.